# c# compare date time dates with time-span parameter

Tags: c#, datetime

Currently I've managed to get my program working so it compared both date time dates, if previous record is before or less than the time now it alerts the end user that patient requires a check up.

I would like to be able to compare today's date and previous date, if there is for example a month apart since the initial booking date it would perform same alert.

```
private void PatientCheckUp()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    Security security = new Security();
    DateTime timenow = DateTime.Now.Date;
    DateTime lastbooking = new DateTime();
    string previousBooking = "";

    try
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionPath;
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Booking.Booking_Last_Booking, Booking.Booking_FkPatientId FROM Booking WHERE Booking.Booking_FkPatientId = @Patient_Id", connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Patient_Id", cbopatientid.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                previousBooking = security.Decrypt(dr["Booking_Last_Booking"].ToString(), security.GetPassword());
            }
        }

        lastbooking = Convert.ToDateTime(previousBooking);

        /*Currently checks if the previous booking date is less than or before today, if so it alerts the user */
        if (lastbooking.Date < timenow.Date)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Patient requires a checks up");
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException sql)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sql.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you actually using a TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(1, 2, 0, 30, 0); ? or is your wording in the header of the question incorrectly implying you use it?

Comment: I didn't mean it literally though if it is required to get the calculation working then sure I'll use it

Comment: Nope a TimeSpan data type isn't required, either of the solutions below should do the trick. P.S. A parameter is also FUNCTIONNAME(paramter1, parameter2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime();

        dt = DateTime.Now;
        dt2 = dt.AddDays(20);


        TimeSpan ts = dt2.Subtract(dt);

        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(dt2.ToString());

        if(ts.Days > 30)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("It has been at least a month since last check up");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It has been "+ ts.Days+" days since last check up");
        }

    }
}
```

The above is a piece of sample code I put together to illustrate how you might be able to do this. You can determine how many days a "Month" should be and then act on it if it exceeds your specified threshold.

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DhRSF5) is the DotNetFiddle I was playing around with

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following.

```
if (timenow.Date - lastbooking.Date).Days > 30)
{
    MessageBox.Show("It's been over 30 days since last checkup.");
}
```